# VSCode extension: How to render colored output in output channel?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have custom output from API and I want to format it to string with some colored values.

Answer (score 2):

The output channel can be colorized with a [TmLanguage grammar](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide). The [Output Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.output-colorizer) extension extension does exactly that:

[image]

You can do this by targeting the `text/x-code-output` mimetype:

```json
"contributes": {
    "languages": [{
        "id": "code-output",
        "mimetypes": [
            "text/x-code-output"
        ]
    }],
    "grammars": [{
        "language": "code-output",
        "scopeName": "code.output",
        "path": "./syntaxes/code-output.tmLanguage"
    }]
}
```

However, since this colorization is mimetype-based, [you can't apply the highlighting to a specific output channel only](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19561). This means that two extensions providing output channel colorization will conflict.

Comment: It is not clear for me... how can I say to output channel use the code-output?

Comment: I think that's basically what declaring the mimetype as `text/x-code-output` does. Seems like you're thinking about it the wrong way around though.

Answer (score 1):

In v1.65 **Proposed Extension API** is the ability to "create an output channel with custom language id" so as to avoid conflicts with other extensions that may be syntax coloring the output.

> ##### Output Channel with Custom Language Id
>
> There are extensions which are able to define token or syntax coloring
> and code-lens features to their output channels given that they are
> text documents (read-only) by themselves. Since all output channels
> share the same lanugage id, these customizations can be wrongly
> applied to other output channels. Hence there has been an ask to
> create an output channel with custom language id so that extension
> authors can define customizations by language. Hence in this
> milestone, we have introduced the
> [proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/35ba35b799a85974079e4a90f59ae7e978ad3def/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.outputChannelLanguage.d.ts#L21)
> to create an output channel with a custom language id. Please try it
> out and give us feedback.

- from [v1.65 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_65.md#output-channel-with-custom-language-id)

Comment: Related PR: [Add optional languageId to window.createOutputChannel API (#19561) #140876](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/140876)